# Gettign most recent file in a directory in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, file-io, powerpoint

I frequently make screenshots of a window and save them into a folder, and then add them to PowerPoint presentations cropped, resized, and aligned in a certain way. To save mouse clicks and make the process reproducible, I'd like to automate this using a Visual Basic macro in PowerPoint.

Currently I have the following:

```
Sub Insert_Picture_3()
Dim oPic As Shape
Set oPic = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddPicture("\\nlamvfs00065\homes\nlkpec\newpic.png", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
    oPic.PictureFormat.CropLeft = 115
    oPic.PictureFormat.CropTop = 85
    oPic.PictureFormat.CropRight = 16
    oPic.PictureFormat.CropBottom = 55
    oPic.Height = 7.5 * 72
    oPic.Left = 0 * 72
    oPic.Top = 0 * 72
    oPic.ZOrder msoSendToBack
End Sub
```

The argument to "AddPicture" is a fixed file called "newpic.png". However, I'd like this to instead be the most recent png file in the directory "\nlamvfs00065\homes\nlkpec", so that I don't have to rename my screenshots to "newpic.png" every time I apply the macro.

I found an example that reads similar to the following:

```
Dim myFile = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("\\nlamvfs00065\homes\nlkpec").OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).First()
```

However, if I enter this line into my Visual Basic editor launched from PowerPoint 2007, I get an error message

> "Compile error: Expected: end of statement"

with the "=" sign highlighted.

Does anybody have any suggestions how I could generate the "myFile" to be passed to "AddPicture" as the most recent png file in the specified directory? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One approach would be to read the filenames into an array, then compare the result from FileDateTime("path_to_file"); if it's greater than the current one, make the new filedatetime the current one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an object you need to dimension it then set it, your code appears to be trying to do both at once.

I am not familiar with DirectoryInfo object but using file system object you can find the last file modified using the following. The example subroutine just illustrates how to call the FindLastModifed function.

To use the code you will need to set a reference to microsoft scripting runtime.

```
Function FindLastModified() As String
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim myFile As Scripting.File
Dim myFiles As Scripting.Files
Dim dteDate As Date
Dim sFilePathName As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set myFiles = fso.GetFolder("\\nlamvfs00065\homes\nlkpec").Files

    For Each myFile In myFiles
        If dteDate < myFile.DateLastModified Then
            dteDate = myFile.DateLastModified
            sFilePathName = myFile.Path
        End If
    Next myFile

FindLastModified = sFilePathName

End Function

Sub Example()
Dim sFileNamePath As String

sFileNamePath = FindLastModified

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for your answer. However, in the PowerPoint Visual Basic editor, I get a compile error at the second line, "Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject", which reads "User-defined type not defined". Are you sure the script will work in a PowerPoint macro? (I've seen examples of other answers which work in Visual Basic, but not in a PowerPoint macro).

Comment: Hi khpeek, the error message you are geting appears to be because you don't have a reference set for the microsoft scripting runtime. To set the reference you need to open the PowerPoint Visual basics editor, chose the tools menu and select references. This will bring up a list of references that the project can use, scroll down to microsoft scripting runtime and then check the box next to it and click ok. The code should then work.

Comment: @khpeek Should probably included the @ char in the last comment, jsut comenting here so that you get a response.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. Indeed had not read your answer carefully enough and had not set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. After setting the reference, the function worked like a charm.